# Peony Computer application

Tags: system

Is the "Peony Computer" application necessary using Ubuntu 20.4? I just upgraded and noticed it in the applications.  Can it be deleted?

Comment: Everything can be deleted and only you know what's important to you. That appears to be the default file manager for the UKUI desktop, so Ubuntu Kylin. Also, it's 20.04 if you want to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's not included in my installation of Ubuntu 20.04.
Peony comes with the UKUI desktop. Have you installed that in the past?

Comment: Was using Ubuntu 18.04LTS and just did the upgrade to the 20.04LTS the other day and this Peony thing was included and wasn't at all familiar with it.  Is that part of the Ubuntu store? Have never used UKUI either.